# HTML Div Classes won't make images to change to new images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slide

This is not my script. I just  copy scripts and learn something of them so I can advance in HTML knowledge.  This code it works only in a part. It shows ok by part of design, but when I press arrows it won't slide to new images

```
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal">
<div class="swiper-wrapper" style="transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d(-630px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="width: 600px; margin-right: 30px;">




<div id="images" style="margin-left:70px;">
         <a onclick="location.href='fallout/'" href="fallout/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/fallout.png">
        <div title="Hacking is now possible without vision!" class="caption">Fallout Version</div>
    </a>


        <a id="green" onclick="location.href='blue/'" href="blue/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/57C9mln.png">
        <div class="caption">GeekTyper Blue</div>
    </a>

                 <a onclick="location.href='writer/'" href="writer/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/writer.png">
        <div title="Hacking is now possible without vision!" class="caption">Writer</div>
    </a>

    <br><br>

    <a style="color:white;padding:20px;" href="mailto:geektyper@outlook.com">Suggest a theme</a>

    </div>



</div>
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="width: 600px; margin-right: 30px;">



<div id="images" style="margin-left:70px;">
    <a id="green" style="background:#bd0101;" onclick="location.href='tegnio/'" href="tegnio/">
        <img src="ASSETS/img/main.png" title="Remembers your settings">
        <div class="caption">Tegnio (Customizable)</div>
    </a>
             <a onclick="location.href='shield/'" href="shield/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/shield.png">
        <div title="" class="caption">SHIELD Version</div>
    </a>
    <a id="green" onclick="location.href='scp/'" href="scp/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bF2tc2V.jpg">
        <div class="caption">SCP</div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="location.href='umbrella/'" href="umbrella/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/umbrella_thumb.png">
        <div class="caption">Umbrella Corp</div>
    </a>
        <a onclick="location.href='aperture/'" href="aperture/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Kb4o0uI.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Aperture Science</div>
    </a>

        <a onclick="location.href='combine/'" href="combine/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sxaHAoi.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Combine</div>
    </a>

        <a onclick="location.href='blackmesa/'" href="blackmesa/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/T1pL2ib.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Black Mesa</div>
    </a>

            <a onclick="location.href='plain/'" href="plain/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RZG9ghe.png">
        <div class="caption">Plain Terminal</div>
    </a>

                <a onclick="location.href='matrix/'" href="matrix/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lHjKmQT.png">
        <div class="caption">Matrix</div>
    </a>


</div>







</div>
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" data-swiper-slide-index="1" style="width: 600px; margin-right: 30px;">











<div id="images" style="margin-left:70px;">
                <a onclick="location.href='dharma/'" href="dharma/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QXMmQwN.png">
        <div class="caption">Dharma</div>
    </a>

                    <a onclick="location.href='tegnio/'" href="tegnio/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DXB4jK7.png">
        <div class="caption">Sliv</div>
    </a>


                    <a onclick="location.href='pony/'" href="pony/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bMwdWFF.png">
        <div class="caption">MLP Typer</div>
    </a>

                    <a onclick="location.href='word/'" href="word/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8QWNpb4.png">
        <div class="caption">Microsoft Word</div>
    </a>

                    <a onclick="location.href='studio/'" href="studio/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tTwtzQz.png">
        <div class="caption">Visual Studio</div>
    </a>

    <a onclick="location.href='lolcode/'" href="lolcode/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OzxnXFb.png">
        <div class="caption">LOLCODE</div>
    </a>


                    <a onclick="location.href='hey/'" href="hey/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5Sqs6jO.png">
        <div class="caption">HE-MAN</div>
    </a>

                        <a onclick="location.href='braile/'" href="braile/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vV4t9Jm.png">
        <div title="" class="caption">Braile Version</div>
    </a>

         <a onclick="location.href='alien/'" href="alien/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/alien.png">
        <div title="" class="caption">Alien Version</div>
    </a>


</div>














</div>
<div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="width: 600px; margin-right: 30px;">




<div id="images" style="margin-left:70px;">
         <a onclick="location.href='fallout/'" href="fallout/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/fallout.png">
        <div title="Hacking is now possible without vision!" class="caption">Fallout Version</div>
    </a>


        <a id="green" onclick="location.href='blue/'" href="blue/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/57C9mln.png">
        <div class="caption">GeekTyper Blue</div>
    </a>

                 <a onclick="location.href='writer/'" href="writer/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/writer.png">
        <div title="Hacking is now possible without vision!" class="caption">Writer</div>
    </a>

    <br><br>

    <a style="color:white;padding:20px;" href="mailto:geektyper@outlook.com">Suggest a theme</a>

    </div>



</div>

<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="width: 600px; margin-right: 30px;">



<div id="images" style="margin-left:70px;">
    <a id="green" style="background:#bd0101;" onclick="location.href='tegnio/'" href="tegnio/">
        <img src="ASSETS/img/main.png" title="Remembers your settings">
        <div class="caption">Tegnio (Customizable)</div>
    </a>
             <a onclick="location.href='shield/'" href="shield/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/shield.png">
        <div title="" class="caption">SHIELD Version</div>
    </a>
    <a id="green" onclick="location.href='scp/'" href="scp/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bF2tc2V.jpg">
        <div class="caption">SCP</div>
    </a>
    <a onclick="location.href='umbrella/'" href="umbrella/">
       <img src="ASSETS/img/umbrella_thumb.png">
        <div class="caption">Umbrella Corp</div>
    </a>
        <a onclick="location.href='aperture/'" href="aperture/">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Kb4o0uI.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Aperture Science</div>
    </a>

        <a onclick="location.href='combine/'" href="combine/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sxaHAoi.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Combine</div>
    </a>

        <a onclick="location.href='blackmesa/'" href="blackmesa/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/T1pL2ib.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Black Mesa</div>
    </a>

            <a onclick="location.href='plain/'" href="plain/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RZG9ghe.png">
        <div class="caption">Plain Terminal</div>
    </a>

                <a onclick="location.href='matrix/'" href="matrix/">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lHjKmQT.png">
        <div class="caption">Matrix</div>
    </a>


</div>







</div></div>

<div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-clickable"><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span></div>

<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

this is script

```
    <script data-rocketsrc="swiper.min.js"></script>


<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 30
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Simplify your code to be only the relevant portion. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Santi    it is only that part.  my div has 3 slide downs. that's why it looks enormously big.

Comment: Error in console ? (Hit [F12] on your keyboard).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette   http://vestigedayz.com/hack/  you can check it here..


Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ; Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  ; Uncaught ReferenceError: UpUp is not defined

Comment: Try to fix the paths to `swiper`... I dont know what can be the use of `data-rocketsrc`. Try with `src` only to see what it does: `<script src="swiper.min.js"></script>` and for `upup`, try this: `<script src="upup.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  i changed to src=" ,  but nothing changed, it still won't change those divs.  


Paths to swiper are good as I can see.

Comment: `upup` seems to be fixed... But not `swipe`. It may be because you don't have the correct path to the file or you don't have the file at all... Try to use a *cdn* [here](https://cdnjs.com/). The rocket.js not also a 404...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  I have the file, and it's the correct path. It's on the same folder as index.html

Comment: Ok... I just refreshed again... Swipe is ok now. You still have 3 errors, One 404 not found on rocket.js and one on an img (opaque2.png). Then there is an error `(index):6 Uncaught TypeError: CloudFlare.__cfjs_block_92a082fe4d_load is not a function` probably caused by the missing rocket.js.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette post as answer. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the console!
*[F12] on the keyboard*

When you have errors, look for `404 (Not Found)` on .js files first.
Then, you'll probaly see errors like `Swiper is not defined` dissapear too.

About `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`, this is due to the use of [Ad Block](https://getadblock.com/). It isn't due to your code.